# Salesforce Survey Responses does not add Amount Used licenses

Tags: survey, salesforce-survey

I am trying to figure out the payment and licensing mechanism of Salesforce Survey

I want to know when does the `Maximum survey responses allowed for an org` `Usage-based Entitlements` adds 1 to the `Amount Used` sum

I am creating a survey invitation, sending it and responding, but still nothing happens, the `Amount Used` sum is empty:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Eventually I want to know if I add manually records to the `Survey Response` object (by dataloader) does that count to licenses or not

Answer (score 0):

The survey response count used would only increase when the Survey response status is "Completed", otherwise it is not counted in the limit.